# getting data from room android with view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-adapter

one week ago I learned the recycler view and work with me fine with adapter and fragment in the XML layout and with hardcoded data or in the shared preferences, but now I learned the room database I followed google developer site on how to display the data and everything and it is not working with me I have been trying for three days but with no result.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.mainTaskView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(new TaskAdapter(tasks));
```

I'm trying to get all items in the database but it keeps giving me null.

[on create code][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txtil.png

here is my repo if you want to see all files.

I can use allowQueriesInMainThread but it's not recommended so I'm trying to achieve the best practice for room and view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need observer `getAllTask()` data cause the data query in workThread, display in mainThread
You can use Room `@QUERY` function to query data and return a LiveData.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tableName")
public LiveData<List<Entity>> getAllTask()
```

```
viewModel.getAllTask().observer(this,new Observer{
    @override
    public void onChange(List<Entity> list){
        adapter.setData(list)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
})
```

I forgot java LiveData.observer. It seems like this